# Weird issue with 404 redirect and no results

Tags: conditionals, redirects, 404, advanced-conditionals

I'm having a strange issue (possible bug?) with the following (simplified) code

```
{if segment_1 == ""}

//Do Stuff//

{if:else}

{exp:channel:entries limit="1" status="Open" url_title="{segment_1}" dynamic="no" parse="inward"}

    {!-- If no results then paramater must be a category for product listing --}
    {if no_results}
        {exp:gwcode_categories cat_url_title="{segment_1}" parse="inward"}

            //Do Stuff//

            {if no_results}
                {redirect="404"}
            {/if}

        {/exp:gwcode_categories}


    {/if}

    ///Do Stuff///


{/exp:channel:entries}

{/if}
```

The problem is with the 404 redirect. If I set 404 page to none in the backend it correctly redirects to a default page saying: "Status: 404 Page Not Found"

However when I change the 404 setting in the backend to show a custom template, it redirects to the 404 page, regardless of whether a category is found by gwcategories or not, ie no results always ends up being true, or is not correctly parsed.

I've tried a number of permutations of the no results conditional, eg: using

{if {results_total} != 1}{redirect="404"}{/if},

which doesn't work either. Even though testing the output of {results_total} outputs 1, it still redirects.

Anyone got any ideas?

Comment: I've found a temporary solution by editing the output for 404 errors in libraries/Template.php, but this is not a good solution.

Answer (score 1):

This is happening because of the first `parse="inward"`. You're telling to the `exp:channel:entries` to parse everything before its inside other modules variables. So, the inner `if no_results` is parsed before the `exp:gwcode_categories`.

Actually, I can't see the point of adding any of the `parse` parameters. The segment variables will be parsed before the modules and plugins in any case.

```
{if segment_1 == ""}

//Do Stuff//

{/if}
{if segment_1}

    {exp:channel:entries limit="1" status="Open" url_title="{segment_1}" dynamic="no"}

        {!-- If no results then paramater must be a category for product listing --}
        {if no_results}
            {exp:gwcode_categories cat_url_title="{segment_1}"}

                //Do Stuff//

                {if no_results}
                    {redirect="404"}
                {/if}

            {/exp:gwcode_categories}

        {/if}

        ///Do Stuff///

    {/exp:channel:entries}
{/if}
```

I also turned your advanced conditional into two simple ones to prevent the second part to be parsed without need.

Comment: I've tried your solution, but it didn't solve the problem, everything worked as before after removing the parse="inward" though, so it clearly wasn't needed. The strange thing to me is still that it works correctly as soon as I set the 404 template to none. Also thanks for the tip with the conditional :)

Comment: This looks like a conflict. I can't read the code of the template parser class right now. Do you mind of to test something? Try to move the `exp:gwcode_categories` into an embed. I update my answer later.